# NSPredicate ( nsdictionary+array+nsdictionary)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsarray, nspredicate

I have try to   NSPredicate but all time get response 0.
check blow code and provide your suggestion where going fault. 
 soureceArray:- 
    {

```
CityId = 0;
TreatmentProgramServices =     (
            {
        TreatmentServicesId = 9;
        TreatmentServicesName = Coed;
    },
            {
        TreatmentServicesId = 1;
        TreatmentServicesName = Intervention;
    },
            {
        TreatmentServicesId = 3;
        TreatmentServicesName = Residential;
    }
);
TreatmentProgrameId = 3;

}
```

---

filterTreatmentServices is array Count is  :- {3}

```
 NSPredicate* updatePre =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%K IN %@)",@"TreatmentProgramServices.TreatmentServicesId" ,filterTreatmentServices];

 filterTreatmentService =[soureceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:updatePre];
```

Please suggest solution

Comment: NSPredicate* updatePre =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TreatmentProgramServices.TreatmentServicesId == %@",@"3"]];

Comment: @balkaransingh Its not working, because issue in TreatmentProgramServices.TreatmentServicesId TreatmentProgramServices is array after that its dic.

Comment: check the answer plz.

Answer (score 0):

plz use this

```
  NSArray *filterArray=[soureceArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id  _Nonnull evaluatedObject, NSDictionary<NSString *,id> * _Nullable bindings) {
                return [[evaluatedObject valueForKey:TreatmentServicesId]  == 3];
            }]];
```